# Redirect output from specific logger to a specific NLog Target

Tags: nlog, asp.net-core-3.1

Using ASP.NET Core3.1 and `NLog`, this is a part of my `NLog.config`:

```xml
<nlog>
   <targets>
        <!-- write logs to file  -->
        <target name="allfile" xsi:type="File" 
                fileName="${aspnet-appbasepath}/AspNetCore_Nlog/nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
                layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}  | url: ${aspnet-request-url} | controller: ${aspnet-mvc-controller}  | action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}"
                archiveAboveSize="1000000"
                maxArchiveFiles="20" />

        <target name="searchedFile" xsi:type="File"
                fileName="${aspnet-appbasepath}/AspNetCore_Nlog/whatIsSearched-${shortdate}.txt"
                layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message}"
                archiveAboveSize="1000000"
                maxArchiveFiles="20"/>
    </targets>

    <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace"  writeTo="allfile" />     
        <logger name="whatIsSearched" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="searchedFile" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

My problem is that, all the logs inside `searchedFile`, also exist in `allfile`.
I need to know if there is a way to exclude a special target from all logs/all file that logs every thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the logging-rule for **whatIsSearched** to the top, and add **final="true"**:

```xml
<rules>
   <logger name="whatIsSearched" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="searchedFile" final="true" />
   <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />
</rules>
```

See also: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules